# Kde Panel Launcher Files Location?

Tags: kde

I was wondering where the files are located for Kde's panel launchers? I can't find anything online. I know where the regular desktop files are, (`~/.local/share/applications/`), but I can't find the launcher files. I currently have a launcher that is not working correctly. When I create the new icon in Kmenuedit, it works fine from within Kde's menu/kickoff. But when i pin that icon to the panel, it doesn't. It is a launcher for IntelliJ IDEA. When I hover over the icon on the panel, all it says is `java`. I checked the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/`, and that one is fine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is in the text file `~/.kde4/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`.

You want to find this section: `[Containments][n][Applets][m][Configuration][Launchers]`, where `n` and `m` are some numbers you need to find out on your system.  There should only be one `Launchers` section for each task manager you have.

If it isn't there, you should look through `[Containments][n][Applets][m]` for one containing the application you are looking for.

Comment: that did it, thank you... In KDE/Plasma 5, that file is now located in ~/.config/

Comment: In my case (CentOS 7.4) it is in `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc` (not `~/.kde4`).

Answer (score 11):

On Debian 9 'Stretch' with KDE Plasma 5.8.6, this is now in:

`~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`

The remaining info is as provided by @TheBlackCat

Comment: Works on vanilla Plasma 5.25 as well (on Arch Linux)