# KDE Plasma Application Launcher Settings file location

Tags: kde, plasma

For the sake of knowing what is happening on my own computer I would like to know where the configuration file is for the KDE Application Launcher. A.k.a. Start Menu.

The application to edit the Application Launcher is called KMenuEdit. What is edited in there is stored somewhere. I would like to know where.

I know there are a ton of articles where to find this. As it seems, at each version of KDE or Plasma this is changed. I have searched, really.

Specifically [Kde Panel Launcher Files Location?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197347/kde-panel-launcher-files-location) is **not** a dupe. This question is from 2015 and KDE has totally changed.

In the manual for KMenuEdit it is stated that the menu hierarchy is stored in

```
menus/applications-kmenuedit.menu
```

I don't have this file on my entire system.

This file should be located in the folder

```
$(qtpaths --paths GenericConfigLocation)
```

Gives the error message:

```
qtpaths: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

Debian BullsEye 11.6
Plasmashell 5.20.5
KDE Frameworks Version 5.78.0
Qt version 5.15.2
Kernel 5.10.0-21-amd64

Comment: I have the same problem; cannot find the "$(qtpaths --paths GenericConfigLocation)" folder in Debian 12.4

Comment: copy "/etc/xdg/menus/kf5-applications.menu" to "$HOME/.config/menus/" and edit the .menu file

Comment: Sorry the elate reaction. Apparently I cannot interpret e-mail correctly. It is not true unfortunately. kf5-applications.menu seems some kind of frame where other directories are included if they exist. They don't exist. There is a recently added folder applications merged. Which contains links to /usr/share/extra-xdg-mens/<name> but those files do not contain the menus entries.